# R-Converting csv data into Market basket data(arules)

Tags: r, data-mining, transpose, arules

**Replicating the Problem with dataset-**
source: https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Online+Retail#
Remove all Columns except InvoiceID & Description

Now you're left with something like this:

InvoiceNo                         Description

1     536365      CREAM CUPID HEARTS COAT HANGER
2     536365   GLASS STAR FROSTED T-LIGHT HOLDER
3     536365 KNITTED UNION FLAG HOT WATER BOTTLE
4     536365      RED WOOLLY HOTTIE WHITE HEART.
5     536365        SET 7 BABUSHKA NESTING BOXES
6     536365  WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER
7     536365                 WHITE METAL LANTERN
8     536366           HAND WARMER RED POLKA DOT
9     536366              HAND WARMER UNION JACK
10    536367       ASSORTED COLOUR BIRD ORNAMENT
11    536367  BOX OF 6 ASSORTED COLOUR TEASPOONS

**NOW, i'd like to run Apriori on this data set**

But since data required for arules must be as ;

trnx. products.
1    A   B  C   D
 
2     D   E  F   A

So, I tried using df_trans:

> df_trans <- as(split(uci_retail$Description, uci_retail$InvoiceNo), "transactions")

Error in asMethod(object) : 
  can not coerce list with transactions with duplicated items

Also, I tried using qdap as an alternative, but no luck.

Could anyone suggest an alternative to transpose the data such that it can be used to perform Market Basked Data or could be able to correct whatever I'm doing wrong.

Regards,
k.soni

Answer (score 0):

Use read.transactions from arules package with  format = "single":

```
txs <- "InvoiceNo;StockCode;Description;Quantity;InvoiceDate;UnitPrice;CustomerID;Country
536365;85123A;WHITE HANGING HEART T-LIGHT HOLDER;6;01/12/2010 08:26;2,55;17850;United Kingdom
536365;71053;WHITE METAL LANTERN;6;01/12/2010 08:26;3,39;17850;United Kingdom  ...........
```

txs is a string extracted  as an example from the file given as an input

```
newdat <- read.table(text=txs, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, sep = ";", header = T)
head(newdat)

trans <- newdat[,1:2]
write.table(trans, "txs.txt", row.names = F, sep = ";")
```

I'm selecting columns InvoiceNo and StockCode (instead of description)

```
trans = read.transactions("txs.txt", format = "single", sep=";",cols = c(1,2));
inspect(trans)
```

We have some duplicates as pointed out by k. Soni

for example

```
> InvoiceNo StockCode 
480962 C577330 S 
480963 C577330 S 
480964 C577330 S
```

may be items bought several times in a tx)

try :

```
df_trans = df_trans [!duplicated( df_trans ), ] 
sum(duplicated( df_trans )) == 0 
df_trans <- as(split( df_trans $StockCode, df_trans $InvoiceNo), "transactions")
```

Comment: > df_trans <- as(split(uci$StockCode, uci$InvoiceNo), "transactions")
Error in asMethod(object) : 
  can not coerce list with transactions with duplicated items <br> I think the problem lies with df_trans not being able to transpose lists with duplicate/ repeated items , and not string or numeric values.